# The encryption won't decrypt

Tags: encryption

I was given an  encrypted copy of the  study guide here, but how do you decrypt and read it???

In a file called pa11.py write a method called decode(inputfile,outputfile).  Decode should take two parameters - both of which are strings.  The first should be the name of an encoded file (either helloworld.txt or superdupertopsecretstudyguide.txt or yet another file that I might use to test your code).  The second should be the name of a file that you will use as an output file.

Your method should read in the contents of the inputfile and, using the scheme described in the hints.txt file above, decode the hidden message, writing to the outputfile as it goes (or all at once when it is done depending on what you decide to use).

The penny math lecture is here.

```py
"""
Program: pennyMath.py
Author: CS 1510
Description: Calculates the penny math value of a string.
"""

# Get the input string
original = input("Enter a string to get its cost in penny math: ")

cost = 0

Go through each character in the input string
for char in original:
    
    value = ord(char)  #ord() gives us the encoded number!

    if char>="a" and char<="z":
        cost = cost+(value-96)    #offset the value of ord by 96
    elif char>="A" and char<="Z":
        cost = cost+(value-64)    #offset the value of ord by 64

print("The cost of",original,"is",cost)
```

Another hint: Don't forget about while loops...

Another hint: After letters -
skip ahead by their pennymath value positions + 2
After numbers - skip ahead by their number + 7 positions
After anything else - just skip ahead by 1 position

The issue I'm having in that I cant seem to get the coding right to decode the file it comes out looking the same. This is the current code I have been using. But once I try to decrypt the message it stays the same.

```
def pennycost(c):
 
     if c >="a" and c <="z":
        return ord(c)-96
    elif c>="A" and c<="Z":
        return ord(c)-64

  
def decryption(inputfile,outputfile):


    with open(inputfile) as f: 
        fo = open(outputfile,"w") 
        count = 0 
        while True: 
            c = f.read(1)
            if not c:
                break;
            if count > 0: 
                count = count -1;
                continue
            elif c.isalpha(): 
                count = pennycost(c) 
                fo.write(c) 
            elif c.isdigit(): 
                count = int(c) 
                fo.write(c) 
            else:
                count = 6
                fo.write(c)

    fo.close() 

inputfile = input("Please enter the input file name: ")

   outputfile = input("Plese enter the output file name(EXISTING FILE WILL BE OVER WRITTEN!): ")

decryption(inputfile,outputfile)
```

Comment: Sample input is missing.

Comment: the sample input is missing in the code?

Comment: The sample input file is missing in the question post.